# how to logout all old session when new session created in WSO2 IS?

Tags: java, android, node.js, backend, wso2-identity-server

We're using WSO2 Identity Server for our web and mobile application.
we need to have only one session at a time like if user login on device A and then try to log in to device B using the same credential the old session should get logged out.
Right now wso2is give session access to both the devices. 
i have search a lot and come to a point it is not possible can anyone please guide me if it is possible or not if yes how?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)